# Ist “Bevor ich das Haus verlassen hatte, schaltete ich die licht aus” gutes Deutsch?

Tags: pluperfect

Entschuldigung, ich bin Engländer.

Ist

> Bevor ich das Haus verlassen hatte, schaltete ich der Computer aus.

gutes Deutsch?

Ich muss den Plusquamperfekt verwenden.

Edit: changed “licht” to “computer”

Comment: Nein, das ist kein gutes Deutsch.

Comment: "Die Lichter" (Mz.) oder "das Licht" (Ez.) (hat wohl nichts mit der Frage zu tun, würde aber erlauben sich besser auf die Frage zu konzentrieren).

Comment: _"Entschuldigung, ich bin Engländer."_ Kein Mensch muss sich für seine Ethnie entschuldigen, das wäre ja noch schöner!

Comment: Engländer ist eine Nationalität, keine Ethnie.

Comment: @user Auch für diese muss man sich nicht entschuldigen.

Comment: Gemeint ist wohl "Meine Muttersprache ist englisch" - auch dafür muss man sich nicht entschuldigen.

Comment: Es ist nicht vollkommen klar, auf was genau deine Frage abzielt - Sollte sie nach der *Zeitenfolge* sein (Plusquamperfekt/Präteritum), dann kann man generell sagen, dass die EInhaltung dieser Folge im Deutschen bei weitem nicht so streng gehandhabt wird wie im Englischen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich weiß nicht genau, wie die Aufgabenstellung aussieht, aber ich nehme
an, dass in der intendierten Lösung die Zeiten vertauscht sein sollen
(Präteritum im Nebensatz, Plusquamperfekt im Hauptsatz):

> Bevor ich das Haus verließ, hatte ich den Computer ausgeschaltet.

Plusquamperfekt in beiden Teilsätzen wäre auch möglich, aber nur
dann, wenn schon das Verlassen des Hauses *vor anderen
berichteten Ereignissen (im Präteritum)* stattfindet.

> *Ich stand an der Bushaltestelle und wartete schon seit zwanzig Minuten auf den Bus.*
>   Bevor ich das Haus verlassen hatte, hatte ich den Computer ausgeschaltet.

Answer (score 0):

> > Bevor ich das Haus verlassen hatte, schaltete ich die licht aus.

---

> ... gutes Deutsch?

Nein, das ist definitiv kein *gutes Deutsch*.
Der Satz müsste wohl richtig lauten

> > Bevor ich das Haus verlassen hatte, schaltete ich **das** Licht aus.

oder

> > Bevor ich das Haus verlassen hatte, hatte ich **das** Licht ausgeschaltet.

---

> Ich muss den Plusquamperfekt verwenden.

Ich denke mal mein letztes Beispiel verwendet das *Plusquamperfekt*, aber mein Grammatik-Schulwissen liegt schon so lange zurück.

Comment: Es ist aber auch _das_ Plusquamperfekt, nicht _den_.